# what is the probability of neither events

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

For the game bridge what is the probability you get NO spades? What is the probability you get no card
higher than 9? What is the probability neither of these occurs?

```
the first one i obtained: (39 choose 13)/(52 choose 13) probability of no spades.
the second one i obtained: (32 choose 12)/(52 choose 13) probability of no card higher than 9
```

how do i calculate the neither part? do i multiply both together?

Comment: hint: take the reverse of both events and calculate the prob. of their intersection